# PowerShell - Remove spaces between words from txt file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am a noob at powershell and still trying to learn scripting but stumbling on the basics.
I have a text file that contains a list of websites

```
Default Websites
Power Shell
Hello World
```

I need to remove the white spaces between the words so I get the outcome below

```
DefaultWebsites
PowerShell
HelloWorld
```

I have tried using the Trim('') command but it is not removing the white spaces.

Here is my original script that removes all white spaces at the beginning and the end and any blank lines. what do I need to add to the script to remove the white spaces in between words?

```
Get-WmiObject -Class IIsWebServerSetting -Namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" | Select ServerComment | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | out-file c:\website.txt
$b = Get-Content -Path C:\website.txt
$b | ForEach {$_.TrimEnd()} | ? {$_.trim() -ne '' } > C:\website.txt
```

Thank you in advance. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with this approach (where the hero is Replace function):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class IIsWebServerSetting -Namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" | Select ServerComment | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | out-file c:\website.txt
$b = Get-Content -Path C:\website.txt
@(ForEach ($a in $b) {$a.Replace(' ', '')}) > C:\Website2.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-replace` command with a simple regex:

```
-replace '\s'
```

> \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

Try this:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText(
        'C:\website.txt',
        ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\website.txt') -replace '\s')
    )
```

Comment: thank you for you response but Eduard Uta solution is less complicated and better for my script as it is a small part of a larger script.